# Open new private window with Capybara and selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

How can I open 2 windows simultaneously but one in private mode?

The capybara's method ([link](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession:open_new_window))

```
open_new_window
```

opens a new window but it doesn't accept any parameters.

Also tried:

```
    page.execute_script 'window.open(link, "mywindow", "private=yes");'
```

But still the new window is not in private mode.

I am using:

- capybara (2.11.0)
- selenium-webdriver (2.53.4)
- Firefox v46

Any ideas?

Comment: What browser are you using with selenium-webdriver?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I am using FireFox v46

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're stuck on obsolete versions of Capybara, selenium-webdriver, and Firefox?  It's going to make giving you a fully correct answer more difficult due to having to work out the syntax for old versions.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, Yes, can't update to newer versions right now. What would the syntax be for the newer version? I also tried `page.execute_script 'window.open(link, "mywindow", "private=yes");'` but it didn't work too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To have a private mode window and a non private mode window you need to have two sessions, and two driver registrations. In the current releases of Capybara, selenium-webdriver, and Firefox with manual session management this could be done as

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox_private do |app|
  firefox_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
  firefox_options.args << "-private"
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: firefox_options)
end
```

and then in your test when you need a private window you would create a new sessions for the private window

```
# Assuming you already have a session going and are interacting with the page
# with `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium` or equivalent set
page.find(...) # everything called on page is happening in the original non-private session

private_session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_firefox_private, Capybara.app)
private_session.visit(...) # anything called on private_session will happen in the private firefox instance
```

Another option would be to use `Capybaara.using_driver`

```
Capybara.using_driver(:selenium_chrome_private) do
  # everything in this block would happen in a private browsing session that is auto created by Capybara (if it hadn't already been created)
  page.visit('/')
end
```

The same is true for the obsolete versions you're using but the Selenium configuration in the driver registration would probably be different.